# Sonata Admin configuration with FosUser but *not* SonataUser

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

As per the title I'm using Sonata Admin and FosUser.

Sonata Admin is working fine for my normal entities; I can do the usual CRUD things.

I then followed [this](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html) example in the docs for hooking into FosUser

My services.yml is thus:

```
sonata.admin.user:
    class:  Company\MyBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Administration", label: "Users" }
    arguments:  [ null, Company\UserBundle\Entity\User, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD ]
    calls:
        -   [ setUserManager, [ @fos_user.user_manager ] ]
```

... and I've created UserAdmin.php:

```
namespace Company\MyBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class UserAdmin extends Admin
{
```

I get a user link in the dashboard but when I follow create new or click to edit my fixtures user (BTW the rendered route is http://dev.url/app_dev.php/admin/company/user/user/create) I get a 500 server error saying "Class does not exist":

```
in /my/path/company/codebase/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php at line 199   
        $class = $this->getAliasNamespace($namespaceAlias) . '\\' . $simpleClassName;
    }
    $proxyClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);
    if ($proxyClass->implementsInterface($this->proxyInterfaceName)) {
        $class = $proxyClass->getParentClass()->getName();
    }
```

I've fiddled with some of the service settings, the only things I can see different to the example are:

1. I've changed the namespace to point to my admin class folder
2. %fos.user.admin.user.entity% wasn't configured anywhere so I've hardcoded it to be Company\UserBundle\Entity\User

I did start to look at adding the SonataUser bundle but as I'm still finding my feet with Symfony2 I figured I'd keep things simple for now and get an unserstanding of what's going wrong here. given the example doesn't mention it as a dependency I assume I can run without it?